# Fix web page as per the screen resolution

Tags: html, css

I am designing a webpage that does not adjust itself as per the screen resolution. It looks OK on higher resolutions but on 1024x768, only the left side of the page is visible. I have tried out putting the whole thing in a container and aligning it to the center but it doesnt work. What would be a way out?

Here's a bit of the HTML:

```
<div id="layer-container" style="position:absolute; background-    image:url(images/bkgrd_final.jpg);">         
    <div id="info-layer" style="position: absolute; text-align: left; left: 0px; top: 2px; height: 747px; z-index: 48; display: block; margin:0 0 0 -285px;" title="">
```

And here is some CSS:

```
div#container {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    overflow:visible;
}
body {
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 1.1875;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #0C0C0C;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center top;
    color: #000000;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: It's pretty hard for folks to help you without seeing the HTML for your page because the answer is "it depends" upon what exactly you're trying to show and how your HTML works.

Answer (score 2):

I would sugest you add mediaqueries with styles for smaller devices.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
```

even better: go "mobile first" by designing you page for mobile devices. then add media-queries with extra styles for bigger devices.